# Custom Sort for specific values on multiple columns in Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Sample table structure

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (
ENTITY_TYPE VARCHAR,
ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR,
PERSON_EID NUMBER,
PERSON_ROLE VARCHAR
);
```

For example, allowed values in ENTITY_TYPE are {"Owner", "President", "Exec"}.

I am implementing a Search API which should return paginated response sorted on below 2 columns with mentioned criteria:

1. ENTITY_TYPE with custom sort order of "Owner" -> "Exec" -> "President"
2. Ascending order of ENTITY_NAME

My project is built on Java with Spring Boot and uses Hibernate and Spring JPA.

Kindly suggest how we can achieve this type of requirement. Please let me know if more information would be required for suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any ideas so far? Maybe an enum with a sortOrder indicator?

Comment: Since we need a paginated response, sort order actually needs to be there when we query the table, not sure how the enum would help. Could you please share an example, I am not aware how to utilize enum for my use case.
And I havent tried anything yet, looking for possible implementations over internet.

Comment: You can incorporate the value to sortOrder mapping in the query with case statements